# Replace Text In Background Image URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simplified, I have this structure:

```
<div id="RelatedPosts1">
    <div class="related-posts-thumb" style="background: url(http://xxxxxxx/s72-c/image-1.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="related-posts-thumb" style="background: url(http://xxxxxxx/s72-c/image-2.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="related-posts-thumb" style="background: url(http://xxxxxxx/s72-c/image-3.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

I wish to replace the "s72-c" with "s320". Thus, changing the size of the image.

This is what I tried with jQuery:

```
<!-- Let's replace low-res with a higher-res -->
$(".related-posts-thumb").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("s72-c", "s320"); 
});
```

I'm guessing this didn't work because the image URL isn't "inside" the element. So I'm not sure how to achieve my desired effect. I'm not a javascript/jQuery expert and I haven't seen any examples addressing anything similar to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you could provide the actual links to some example images that would help. I think I can help you do this but I need example images of each size to create an example to show you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure when you want this to trigger, so I'll just make this an on click...

```
 $('.related-posts-thumb').each(function() {
     $(this).attr("style", $(this).attr("style").replace("s72-c", "s320"));
 });
```

JSFiddle example (click on the background):

http://jsfiddle.net/wdc6ydtk/1/

Comment: This works? That's awesome. I didn't realize you could treat the entire style of an element as a string. If you can provide an example you get a +1 from me :)

Comment: A click even isn't what I was looking for. I tried to solve the issue though using your example and I still couldn't quite get it.

Comment: This example should work fine have a look at the jsfiddle @Xarcell

Comment: This is what I used from your example to get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/wdc6ydtk/2/ If you update your answer I will accept it, assuming that "text" is correct way to do this.

Comment: @Xarcell  Sure, I just used .html, but that should have the same effect. On load it will change the image. I have updated my answer.

Comment: just use `.each()` .. do not abuse other methods. It makes the code really hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.css()` method with the function parameter option](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)

```
$('.related-posts-thumb').css("background-image",function(idx,current){
    return current.replace('s72-c','s320');         
 });
```